# Xamarin Forms Picker - how set line height for title / remove padding inside title?

Tags: c#, forms, xamarin, mobile, picker

I want to lower +32 in Picker. Title to the level of '123...' in Entry.PlaceHolder. How can I do it?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/x6fl4.png

Code:

```
<StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
    <Picker Title="+32" />
    <Entry Placeholder="123 456 789" Keyboard="Numeric" />
</StackLayout>
```

HeightRequest and Margin don't change anything. I tried also custom renderer and nothing.

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(Picker), typeof(CustomPickerRenderer))]
namespace App.Droid.Renderers
{
    public class CustomPickerRenderer : PickerRenderer
    {
        public CustomPickerRenderer(Context context) : base(context) { }

        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Picker> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);

            if (Control == null || e.NewElement == null) return;

            Control.LineHeight = 60;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Any particular reason you need to align an Entry with a Picker? A picker having the ability to scroll at any given time will not keep your alignment consistent. I think possibly a tap gesture recognizer on either a label or a button  that will show the picker might be a lot easier to design throughout all layouts in Xamarin Forms.

Comment: Could you show your complete xaml codes as i could not reproduce your issue on my side

Comment: and you could try to set  `Control.SetSingleLine(true);` in your renderer.

Comment: Hi friend i am not able to replicate this issue